# Python socket.gethostbyaddr throwing error

Tags: python, sockets, lookup

I am reading IP addresses from a CSV file into a pandas data-frame, then extracting the IP(column) from the row. Then I try to do a lookup to get the PTR record, but I am getting the following error:

```
'141.217.9.86'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate-csv.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "populate-csv.py", line 18, in main
    name, alias, addresslist = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host
```

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import subprocess
# import shlex
# import pydig
import socket  

def main(): 
  # file_name = 'ukhan-systems-wihtout-secondary.csv'
  file_name = 'input.csv'
  df = pd.read_csv (file_name)
  # print(df)

  for row in range(len(df)):
    # print(df.loc[row, "Device_name"], df.loc[row, "ip"])

    ip =  (df.loc[row, "ip"]).strip()
    print(repr(ip))
    name, alias, addresslist = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Here is what the CSV looks like:

```
141.217.9.86,141.217.9.86,,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,Medium
141.217.9.85,141.217.9.85,,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,Medium
141.217.9.83,141.217.9.83,,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,Medium
141.217.9.73,141.217.9.73,praxi.gmu.edu,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,High
141.217.9.68,141.217.9.68,,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,High
141.217.9.64,141.217.9.64,icsa.gmu.edu,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,High
141.217.9.63,141.217.9.63,,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,High
141.217.9.62,141.217.9.62,,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,Medium
141.217.9.35,141.217.9.35,,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,High
141.217.9.33,141.217.9.33,,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,High
141.217.9.32,141.217.9.32,,jdoe123,"ACME Incorporated",jane_doe,,High
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting from `gethostbyaddr()`

> socket.herror: [Errno 1] Unknown host

is pretty clear - there is no hostname records in the DNS for the IP address you are querying.

It's even more clear from the shell:

```sh
$ host 141.217.9.86
Host 86.9.217.141.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

I suggest wrapping the `gethostbyaddr()` in a try..except block so that you can handle unknown host addresses cleanly

Incidentally, if you run each IP address in your data file through `host`, then you'll see that none of them have hostname records.